# swapping array elements without a temporary variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, shuffle, temporary

The following code:

```
var words = ['javascript', 'hmtl', 'css', 'python'];
            
words[0] = words[3];
words[3] = words[0];
        
alert(words);
```

...gives the below:

```
python,hmtl,css,python
```

1. Why receive I `python,hmtl,css,python`, instead of `python,hmtl,css,javascript`, if there is no temporary variable?

Would you Guys be able to help with the above, please?

Comment: Is this some coding challenge?

Comment: Why? because you overwrite the value and read it on the next line??

Comment: Because you first assign `'python'` to position zero of the array. Then `words[0]` is `'python'` and you assign this to position three of the array

Comment: You would get the expected result if there was indeed a temp variable for swapping values.

Comment: `console.log('befor: ', words); [words[0], words[3]] = [words[3], words[0]]; console.log('after: ', words);` ---> swap without temp variable. Will get you `python,hmtl,css,javascript`. Now, you please figure out why it works & share your conclusions with all.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to swap without a temp variable use the ES6 array destruction syntax; simply do the following `[words[0],words[3]]=[words[3],words[0]]`

Comment: Brilliant solution